# Joining Table error

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I've Table1 created that has composite keys (column1,column2,column3)

```
CONSTRAINT table_PK PRIMARY KEY (column1,column2,column3)
```

Table 2 has composite key (column1,column4)

```
CONSTRAINT table2_FK FOREIGN KEY (column1)
  REFERENCES table1 (column1)
CONSTRAINT table2_column4_FK FOREIGN KEY (column4)
  REFERENCES table3 (column4)
```

However I'm not able to join table 2 to table 1. Between the 2 tables, the only referencing column should only be column1

However I'm receiving an error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
*Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
           gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
           key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
           catalog view
```

I've tried check the constraint and everything seems right.

When i tried using the interface to create table, it did not work as well.

```
The number of FK columns (2) does not equal to the number of referenced columns (3)
```

From what I see, they require me to have an equal amount of column to have reference to another table. However  I don't think it's necessary. It should only require 1 column right? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that your foreign key constraing needs to reference all three of the columns that comprise your primary key on `table_PK`.

Since you're basically saying that each primary key is determined to be unique based up the combination of values in each of the three columns (i.e. each [tuple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)), the foreign key constraint needs to reference all three columns in order to determine which unique record/tuple is associated with the key in `table_PK`.